# Did Parshurama met Sharavan Kumar as depicted in this show

Tags: scripture, puranas

I have seen a clip of Parshurama and Shravan Kumar. Can any one tell if this is mentioned in any scriptures or is it just made for social message.

[Parshuram aur Shravan](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VzqIPyQ3AQA)

Comment: I haven't seen this mention in śāstras. But if they really met or not, we can't say anything.